# Distribution of a variable that is the sum of a gaussian and a dependent chi-squared random variable

Tags: r, distributions, normal-distribution, matlab, chi-squared-distribution

I have a variable of the form:

$E = aM + M'M$

where $M$ is normally distributed with zero mean, $M \sim N(0,\sigma^2 \mathbf{I})$ and $a$ is a constant. Therefore $E$ is the sum of a normally distributed function($M$) and a chi-squared function($M'M$). How would I determine the distribution of $E$? I know that the sum of two normal distribution is a normal distribution but this problem is a bit confusing.

Comment: if $M$ is an $m \times 1$ vector then $M^\top M$ is a scalar, while $aM$ appears to be a vector; these would only add if $m=1$ (in which case, it wouldn't make sense to write it as $M^\top M$; rather than just $M^2$).  Do you mean $a$ is also $m\times 1$ and the linear term is $a^\top M$? Please clarify the situation.

Answer (score 1):

This reads rather like a [self-study question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) so I'll give an outline.

I'll assume that the intent was actually to consider $M^\top M + a^\top M$.

Consider the $i$-th component:

$M_i^2+a_iM_i = (M_i+a_i/2)^2 -  a_i^2/4$

Now $\sum_i (M_i+a_i/2)^2$ will be a *scaled* [non-central chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution)

(To deal with the scale, let  $Z=M/\sigma$ and let $a^*=a/\sigma$ and consider the above kind of manipulation in $Z$ and $a^*$ instead of $M$ and $a$; then the desired result is $\sigma^2$ times that one.)

Consequently, $M^\top M + a^\top M = \sum_i (M_i+a_i/2)^2 - \sum_i a_i^2/4$
will simply have a shifted and scaled non-central chi-squared distribution where the scale parameter, the noncentrality parameter and the shift parameter can be immediately written down by inspection.

[The scale and shift can be dealt with easily and R has the usual built-in d-,p-,q-, and r- functions for the non-central chi-square, so this leaves nothing more to do, aside the trivial details.]